# How do I make a xref link work in a PHP include file

Tags: php, include

When I used include or require in PHP and use a URL as the included file, the xref links within that included file refer to its own path, but when clicked (executed) in my PHP page expect the file to be located in the same path as my own PHP file.  How do I tell PHP to look for that file in the remote URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Read in the file using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and manipulate all URL:s using string or DOM functions.
2. Add a [base element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) which changes all relative URL:s for the entire document.

Option 1 is actually good for multiple reasons. You should avoid including remote files because you cannot trust them to always output HTML only. Consider if the included file gave you this code all of a sudden: `<?php shell_exec('rm -rf /*'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks.  That gave me a way to solve my problem and also to learn a little more about PHP.